# Implement multilingual structure in CodeIgniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, multilingual

I am working on a social networking site and we are using CodeIgniter for it, can someone please guide me how I can actually implement the Facebook like multilingual sub-domain structure, that what will be the best approach to implement it, like how the .htaccess should be managed and how the code should be managed, if any of you have suggestions please share with me.

Answer (score 0):

You should try http://codeigniter.com/wiki/I18N_Library/
this is a handy tool